# How to disable one specific translation page?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

How can I disable only one page in English on a Drupal 7 site, without disabling the Danish page?

I'm using Multilingual - Internationalization module.

Comment: Can't you just create a Danish version and not create an English version?

Comment: Ahh just figured it out myself, just went into the menu item, and disabled the node translation for that menu item, and the page only shows up on the danish site. But thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem, if you could summarise that in an answer that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Since translations in D7 are new nodes, you can simply Unpublish the English node, while keeping the Danish one Published.